# Chaining Effects in Idris

Tags: idris

After playing around a bit Idris and its Effects tutorial examples, I finally figured out how to chain effects. Not sure if chain is the correct word, but I basically mean one effect implemented in terms of another.

In this example I have an Effect which I call Lower. It directly calls to IO. Then I have an Effect which I call Higher, I intend to implement its handlers using Lower and NOT calling IO directly (or for that matter, mentioning IO anywhere near it).

I finally got it to work with a minor problem which I cant figure out :

```
module Main

import Effects

data Lower : Effect where

  LLog : String -> Lower () () (\_ => ())
  LGreet : String -> Lower () () (\_ => ())
  LFarewell : String -> Lower () () (\_ => ())

Handler Lower IO where

  handle _ (LLog msg) k = do
    putStrLn $ "log: " ++ msg
    k () ()

  handle _ (LGreet msg) k = do
    putStrLn $ "greeting: " ++ msg
    k () ()

  handle _ (LFarewell msg) k = do
    putStrLn $ "farewell: " ++ msg
    k () ()

LOWER : EFFECT
LOWER = MkEff () Lower

data Higher : Effect where

  HGreet : String -> Higher () () (\_ => ())
  HFarewell : String -> Higher () () (\_ => ())

lgreet : String -> Eff () [LOWER]
lgreet msg = do
  call $ LGreet msg
  call $ LLog "greeting received"

lfarewell : String -> Eff () [LOWER]
lfarewell msg = do
  call $ LFarewell msg
  call $ LLog "farewell received"

(Monad m, Handler Lower m) => Handler Higher m where

  handle _ (HGreet msg) k =
    do
      runInit [()] (lgreet msg)
      k () ()

    {- FIXME: This doesnt work, why ?
    where
      lgreet : String -> Eff () [LOWER]
      lgreet msg = do
        call $ LGreet msg
        call $ LLog "greeting received"
    -}

  handle _ (HFarewell msg) k =
    do
      runInit [()] (lfarewell msg)
      k () ()

HIGHER : EFFECT
HIGHER = MkEff () Higher

dummy : Eff () [HIGHER]
dummy = do
  call $ HGreet "hi"
  call $ HFarewell "bye"

main : IO ()
main = do
  runInit [()] dummy
```

See the FIXME comment I made above. If I move the lgreet definition inside where clause it fails to compile with following error message :

```
When checking type of Effects.Main.Higher, m implementation of Effects.Handler, method handle, lgreet:
Type mismatch between
        () (Type of (\underscore => ()) x)
and
        Type (Expected type)
chain1.idr:64:6:When checking right hand side of main with expected type
        IO ()

Can't find implementation for Handler Higher IO
```

Whereas if I keep it outside it works fine, produces the intended output :

```
greeting: hi
log: greeting received
farewell: bye
log: farewell received
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok found the problem, idris is having trouble inferencing the type of this function in the definition of data Higher :

```
\_ => ()
```

Explicitly specifying the type fixes the problem :

```
data Higher : Effect where

  HGreet : String -> Higher Unit Unit (the (Unit->Type) (\_ => ()))
  HFarewell : String -> Higher () () (the (Unit->Type) (\_ => ()))
```

Comment: related: if you want to avoid declaring functions, you can do `runInit [...] $ do ...`. But if you need to restrict the type of the effect within this nested do, doing `the (Eff foo [BAR])` will fail because of incorrect/inadequate inferencing, use `the (EffM m foo [BAR] (\_ => ..))`, ofc replace `m` with whatever variable you are using in your Handler declaration.